# What is intuition behind boundary condition on H field and magnetic field B?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, boundary-conditions

I read about boundary conditions, perpendicular and parallel components below and above the surface in Griffiths' "Introduction to Electrodynamics" book. I'm unable to understand it intuitively. Can someone elaborate these boundary conditions on $H$ and $B$?

Answer (score 2):

In order to understand the boundary conditions on magnetic fields, you first need to understand how those fields are created. The source of magnetic fields is the current, which produces a swirling field pattern around it. How do you measure that swirl at an interface? This is the meaning of an expression like $H_{\parallel}^{1}-H_{\parallel}^{2}$. Maxwell's equations tells us that the presence of surface current $j_{s}$ induces such a swirl at the interface between two regions, or in a mathematical language

$$H_{\parallel}^{1}-H_{\parallel}^{2}=j_{s} \tag{1}$$

As for the perpendicular parts, you know that

$$B_{\perp}^{1}-B_{\perp}^{2}=0 \tag{2}$$

Now keep in mind that there is no such a thing "magnetic charge", and thus the net magnetic flux leaving a volume must vanish. This statement is exactly what Eq. $(2)$ is saying, since in our case the volume can be taken to be a very short cylinder surrounding the interface - such that only its bases contribute to the flux.